# Show only digits and period(.) on soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

- I have used this code to display only numbers and period for Edittext input and it works fine.

  edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

### My Observation

- I have noticed that when i run this code to Android 2.3.6 it shows me only digits,and if i run this code to Android 4.2.2 it shows me digits and ("+","*",")","(","=",) signs also.
- I want to know that if this code depends on OS version? And if yes then what should i do for displaying only **DIGITS** whether i run this code to any android version?

Comment: That can also depend on the input method being used, but users should not be able input non-numeric values. Can you try to press +, - and other characters and see if you can actually enter them into `EditText` field?

Comment: yes it doesn't allowed the user to input them but it displays on soft keyboard. I don't want to even show them in keyboard

Comment: Have You tried to create own keyboard (there's lot of examples at SO and Yours case looks quite simple - only 11 keys are needed)?

Comment: Yes but any how i don't want to use custom keyboard. I want to know that is it possible through native keyboard?

Comment: It is up to the developer of the soft keyboard to show/hide special characters. So, no, it is not possible.